# Can I level quickly by exploiting level drain and restoration?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, necromancy

Suppose an archmage has an apprentice, a level 1 wizard who he wants to train quickly. He attempts the following:

1. He goes adventuring with the apprentice. The archmage fights moderately powerful monsters with ease, and within a day the apprentice has reached wizard level 3.
2. The archmage hires a vampire to strike the apprentice with his energy drain attack, causing him to acquire two negative levels, which ultimately cause him to lose two levels. He is reduced to wizard level 1 again.
3. The archmage repeats the first two steps nine times, so that the apprentice has gained and lost two levels ten times, twenty levels in total.
4. The archmage hires a cleric to cast *greater restoration* on the apprentice. He immediately regains all twenty of his lost wizard levels, and is now a 21st level wizard.

Now, no reasonable DM would allow such cheese. But, **rules as written**, does this process work?

Comment: This sorta breaks the 4th wall for me. How would the characters get an in-world understanding of the leveling mechanic?

Comment: @Jason_c_o If their were clearly measurable and absolutely quantifiable breakpoints in creature's skills and abilities, how would creatures *not* understand leveling? `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan because those breakpoints are a mechanical representation of the continuous experience gain of your character. From the character's point of view, those breakpoints don't exist, they are more gradual.

Comment: @Jorn Respectfully, I disagree. For example, feats and being able to cast spells of a certain level are *switches* not *dials.* A creature doesn't gradually gain the benefit of, for example, the feat Combat Expertise or Improved Trip but, instead, suddenly and all at once gains those benefits. Similarly, a caster doesn't gradually develop the ability cast *fireball* but, instead, one day he can't cast it and the next he can. Those are quantifiable within the game universe. Nonetheless, I agree that *how* the DM justifies in his campaign such sudden changes is totally at the DM's discretion.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well spells for a wizard at least are a product of research, which I can confirm is essentially a continuous process (I'm not a wizard, but am a researcher).  Maybe sorcerers feel the power slowly bubbling up and coalescing until at last they can grasp and manifest it properly.  But, yes, for the most part I agree: the system allows and encourages sudden and drastic improvements in ability acquisitions, and "you learn it quickly but progressively during your X days of downtime" is not meaningfully different from "you learn it instantly".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Sure, and that continuous research is even baked into the game… for wizards, anyway: "Wizards perform a certain amount of spell research between adventures" off-screen to gain their free level-up spells, for example (*PH* 179-80). Being able to *cast* those spells, on the other hand, *isn't* a gradual process! But, yeah, what *everybody else* does is up to the DM.

Comment: This is a bit off topic but in online MUDs something like this could happen, often on hit points. You find a way to go to zero or negative hit points without dying (often invoking a level drain in the process) and you get back with huge amounts of HP. But it was due to bugs in the code, not to Rules-as-intended

Comment: Using *Damp Power* combined with one of the various status monitoring effects can allow one to gain an exact understanding of what 1hp and 1dmg is. Add in ability drain/damage to figure out what 1 ability point is. The XP transfer amulet and feat will allow one to understand experience points. From there it is simply a matter of time and research to develop in-context GUIs and HUDs for all sentient beings along with powers and spells which reveal stats.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> restoring the creature to the highest level it had previously attained

<sup>(from *greater restoration*)</sup>

The creature had never attained any level above 3rd. When *greater restoration* is cast on it, it is restored... to 3rd level. Which it already has. I.e. nothing happens.

*Restoration*, rather than *greater restoration*, doesn’t mention anything about “previously attained,” though. But, even rules as written, the entire *restoration* line uses, unsurprisingly, the word “restore.” That doesn’t have a game-definition, so we use the English definition, and you cannot restore that which was never there in the first place. This never works.

Answer (score 11):

**No**

Ignoring the cheese (which I shall touch on briefly) there is one key problem with this scenario.

Step 1:  "The archmage fights moderately powerful monsters with ease" - if the apprentice is not participating in the battle or contributing significantly then the GM will not award them the bonus.  This one is a bit of a judgement call though, not necessarily a fatal flaw.  (If I were going to try this on then I would give the apprentice a wand of fireballs, cloak of the bat and dust of disappearance, locate a band of low level monsters and tell him to fly over and fireball them solo - that way he gets all the XP.  I still have not met a GM who would buy it though.)

Step 2:  Brutal though it is, the important thing here is that the apprentice must not just gain negative levels, he must fail his Fortitude save and actually lose levels after 24 hours.  No rules issues, but the important thing is that the apprentice who was level 3 is now level 1.  Otherwise he is still a level 3 character with a nasty disadvantage who requires more and more XP for each further level.

Step 3:  Rinse and repeat steps 1 and 2 - no problems from a rules perspective (except for the ongoing judgement call on the validity of step 1).

Step 4:  Here is where the wheels fall off this recipe.  Restoration, Greater, states (emphasis mine):

> This effect also reverses level drains by a force or creature,
>   *restoring the creature to the highest level it had previously attained*.

So, this will restore the hapless apprentice to level 3, as this is the highest level he had previously attained.  It does not matter how many times he has previously attained level 3, he cannot be restored to a level greater than 3 by RAW.